# tensor flow giving nan loss when running with convolutional network

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to create a convolutional NN for house numbers images in tensorflow
http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/

I am getting cost as nan right in the first step when I am running my code.
Here is the link to the github where I have put in my code
https://github.com/ibnipun10/TensorFlow/blob/master/convhouseNumbers.ipynb

Please let me know where I am making mistake

Comment: I can't see anything wrong when looking over the code, but the only time I ever got NaN's in TensorFlow, I used the GradientDescent optimizer. Could you try using a different Optimizer, such as tf.train.AdamOptimizer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loss is NaN because the gradient is just exploded.

Your code looks ok, but your learning rate is high. Try with a lower learning rate (like `1e-2` or `1e-3`) and see if the gradient still explode.

In addiction, I don't know if the images you're using in training have just been converted to float values and scaled in order to have zero mean and unit norm, but usually this is a step needed when working with images that helps to avoid gradient explosions.

Tensorflow have a function for that: [`tf.image.per_image_whitening`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/image.html#per_image_whitening)

Comment: Let me do the same and will let you know if it worked, thanks BTW